# Coturn server gave code=701 TURN allocate request timed out

Tags: webrtc, coturn

I have setuped a Coturn server using it's docker image:

```
docker run -d --network=host --name coturn -v $(pwd)/turnserver.conf:/etc/coturn/turnserver.conf coturn/coturn
```

and this is turnserver.conf:

```
realm=some.domain
server-name=turnserver
listening-ip=0.0.0.0
external-ip=172.21.196.122
listening-port=3478
log-file=stdout
fingerprint
verbose
user=hmd:hmd123
lt-cred-mech
```

when I test it using https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ it gave me this error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is port 3478 _UDP_ (and not only TCP) on the host where coturn's container runs reachable from the browser?